# Meteor React form select selected

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am working with Meteor and React and have the following component:

```
User = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return { selectValue: this.props.user.roles[0] };
  },
  handleChange( event ) {
    this.setState({ selectValue: event.target.value });
  },
  render() {
    let message ='You selected ' + this.state.selectValue;

    return (
      <tr>
        <td>
          {this.props.user.profile.name.first}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.user.profile.name.last}
        </td>
        <td>
          {this.props.user.emails[0].address}
        </td>
        <td>
          <select name="userRole" value={this.state.selectvalue} onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <option value="admin">Admin</option>
            <option value="manager">Manager</option>
            <option value="employee">Employee</option>
          </select>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </td>
      </tr>
    );
  }
});
```

The `this.props.user.roles` in `getInitalState` is a value coming from the database. The component is doing exactly what I want apart from the select option is not showing the value I want. This is what is rendered out on screen:

[image: See how my actual selected value is represented in the option]

My question is how would I add a `selected="selected"` to the option so it represents the correct role?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try this https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/23302/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dont need to add `selected="selected"`, you just have a typo.

> value={this.state.selectValue}, v -> V

Comment: Thanks @jackypan1989 it was early when I started work today!

Comment: Haha. 'cause I live in the other side of earth. :p